# Is every function a relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In other words: is it a requisite that there exists at least one  ordered pair of the form $(x,y)$ for every  $x\in X$. where $x\in X$, $y\in Y$ and the relation is of the form $XrY$?

Comment: Yes. Functions are special kinds of relations.

Comment: so then stricly less than would not be a relation between sets X={1,3,5,7,9} and Y= {2,4,6,8}??

Comment: Don't think of relations as "check formulas", $$R=\{(1,2),(1,4),(1,6),(1,8),(3,4),\ldots,(3,8),\ldots,(7,8)\}$$ is a prefectly valid relation for $X,Y$.

Comment: but there is no ordered pair of the form (9,y)

Comment: What is the problem with that? It is not a requirement that all elements of $X$ must be related with at least one of $Y$ when considering any relation. That is only in the case of functions!

Comment: oh,ok, that was my question. Thanks ;)

Comment: For example, $R=\{(1,2),(5,6)\}$ is another perfectly valid relation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. The definition of a function is a relation which has an additional property: if both $(x,y)$ and $(x,z)$ are in the relation then $y=z$.

More to the point, though, the notation $f\colon X\to Y$ means three things:

1. $f$ is a function, which is a relation with this special property.
2. $\operatorname{dom}(f)=X$, so **every** point in $x$ appears as the left coordinate of some ordered pair in $f$.
3. $\operatorname{rng}(f)\subseteq Y$, so if $(x,y)\in f$ then $y\in Y$.

There are contexts where we remove the second requirement. For example in forcing we often want to talk about partial functions from a large domain, so we omit the second requirement. But this is usually mentioned explicitly in the text.

Comment: ["For example in forcing...](http://stickerish.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/AreYouKiddingMeBlackSS.png) =D

Comment: So then the relationship < (strictly lessthan) between sets X={2,4,6,8} and Y={1,3,5,7} where the relation is of the form XrY is not a relation? (Since no element is smaller than 8)

Comment: @Omnitic: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: If it where a relation of the form XrY then the ordered pairs would be {(2,3),(2,5),(2,7),(4,5),(4,7),(6,7)}. But none of these pairs are of the form (8,y) where $y \in Y$. My question is: this is not a relation of the form XrY right?

Comment: @Omnitic: Is the relation between the sets, or between their elements? If the relation is between the sets then the object should be $(X,Y)$. Moreover, I don't see why you care about it being a function or not.

Comment: sorry, I'm going to try to be more concise this time. Does every subset of the cartesian product of X and Y define a relation between the elements of X and Y?

Comment: @Omnitic: Yes. That is the definition of a relation. A set of ordered pairs.

Comment: @Omnitic: No problem.

Answer (score 3):

As Halmos says, see a relation (in particular a function) in terms of something that *is*, not something that *does*.

A relation is a subset of $X\times Y$. That is all. You choose pairs $(x,y)$ with $x\in X,y\in Y$. If $(x,y)\in R$; then $x$ stands in relation with $y$.

A function is a special kind of relation: all elements of $X$ must be related to at least one element of $Y$. Moreover, this element $x\in X$ is related to is unique, that is, $x$ cannot be related to more than one element of $Y$.

So, for example, a function $f:\{1,3,6,5\}\to\{a,b,c\}$ is $$f=\{(1,a),(3,b),(6,b),(5,c)\}$$

while a relation can be $$R=\{(1,a),(1,b),(3,b),(3,c)\}$$

Comment: When you say "cannot be related to more than two..."  does "more" mean "weakly more"?  Or is it just a typo?

Comment: @TrevorWilson Than was a bad bad typo. Sorry.